# How to disable symbol loading in gdb-7.10?

Tags: debugging, gdb, debug-symbols, pstack

In the old versions of gdb there was an option, `-readnever`, which suppressed symbol loading. Can I achieve the same result with gdb-7.10? This is needed to just stack traces, not for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look through the source for older versions of `gdb` and could not find this option.  After a bit of hunting I believe that this option is a [RedHat patch](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/gdb.git/commit/?id=658b48942f4305ce40761b13bc23d1d1186229a2).  I guess later versions of gdb released by RedHat will include that patch, alternatively, if you are building gdb yourself you could apply that patch.

Comment: I'm writing script, I can't say users to build gdb manually before running script :) probably I just can check and add -readnever if the version is old